# How do I create a custom one-page checkout?

Tags: checkout, custom

I'm currently in the process of building a booking module for a client's Magento website.

I've come to the checkout process and discovered I could (if I know how) use Magento's built in checkout classes and methods.

What I'm unsure about is how to go about this. I would need to give the user the ability to:

- Either login, register or continue as guest
- Input their billing details (if they choose to continue as guest)
- Some completely custom fields, a mixture of both checkboxes and text inputs
- Verify order and input payment information
- Agree to terms and conditions before proceeding and continuing with order

I could really do with someone just breaking down how the one-page checkout process works so I can piece together how it all links.

Answer (score 1):

The checkout might be one of the trickiest parts to customize in Magento. Divisionlab did a tutorial on modifying the checkout you could check.

http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/onestep-checkout-a-magento-tutorial-part-1-steps-1-4-of-12/

Comment: Hi Sander, Thanks for your quick reply. I had come across Division Lab's tutorial earlier today, but I don't think it covers what I'm looking to do. Is there much else you can do to help?

Comment: I haven't found any good documentation myself yet. the changes I did myself involved a lot of backtracing Magento code and checking the quote itself to see what it needs to be converted to an order. Basically you'll need addresses first to get shipment method and billing method and from there you can calculate the totals